# Clojure: Is it possible to make a macro to create the two elements in a single condp clause?

Tags: macros, clojure

The condp clauses look like this:

```
      "plet" (make-adj 2 "ète")
      "iet"  (make-adj 2 "ète")
      "nin"  (make-adj 1 "gne")
```

I want to add the condition to the `make-adj` function call without repeating the condition twice in one line. I'd like a macro that turns this:

```
(test-make-adj "plet" 2 "ète")
(test-make-adj "iet" 2 "ète")
(test-make-adj "nin" 1 "gne")
```

Into this:

```
      "plet" (make-adj 2 "ète" "plet")
      "iet"  (make-adj 2 "ète" "iet")
      "nin"  (make-adj 1 "gne" "nin")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`condp` has built-in functionality to support this kind of thing:

```
(condp #(if (= %1 %2) %1) condition
  "plet" :>> #(make-adj 2 "ète" %)
  "iet"  :>> #(make-adj 2 "ète" %)
  "nin"  :>> #(make-adj 1 "gne" %))
```

`#(if (= %1 %2) %1)` is a binary function which checks if its arguments are equal, returning the first argument if they are or `nil` otherwise.

`:>>` makes it so that the result of evaluating the predicate on `condition` and e.g. `"plet"` gets passed to the `#(make-adj ...)` function. With the above predicate this means that if `(= "plet" condition)` is `true`, then `"plet"` gets passed on to `#(make-adj ...)`. See `(doc condp)` for more info.

If this still feels like too much typing, you can create a helper function:

```
(defn make-adj* [n s]
  (fn [c] (make-adj n s c))
```

Then use it like so:

```
(condp #(if (= %1 %2) %1) condition
  "plet" :>> (make-adj* 2 "ète")
  ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

First a function to make one of the condp clauses

```
(defn test-make-adj [x num y]
  `(~x (make-adj ~num ~y ~x)))
```

Then a macro to assemble the clauses into a condp expression

```
(defmacro adj-condp [pred expr & clauses]
  `(condp ~pred ~expr
     ~@(mapcat test-make-adj clauses)))
```

ps: i'm not at my repl so i cant test this, please edit :)

Comment: I've edited in a few fixes to the code. Apart from removing two minor bugs, I've replaced `(apply concat (map ...))` with `mapcat` and adjusted indentation as a matter of style. Hope you're ok with that.